# Iphone 5 : Recording video in slow motion

Tags: video, iphone, camera

I know It's one feature of iphone 5s, but can iPhone 5 do it? or can you record 60fps or 120fps with iphone 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow motion video is not available on models below iPhone 5s with stock software. There are camera apps that simulate it, but the hardware in iPhone 5 is apparently not physically capable of going above 60 FPS.

It is possible on jailbroken devices to unlock this 60 FPS mode, or at least [it was as of iOS 7](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/973271) (a few years ago).